# Optimised range checking and returning a value

Tags: c++, c, if-statement, switch-statement

I have below function which returns a value based on the input. I need to make this code as fast as possible, without using divison or modulo operator or loops. 
Each consecutive value is separated by amount almost equal to 6553.

```
int GetScalingFactor(int input)
{
    unsigned int factor = 0;

    if(input < 13107) factor = 72816;
    else if(input < 19660) factor = 81918;
    else if(input < 26214) factor = 93621;
    else if(input < 32767) factor = 109225;
    else if(input < 39321) factor = 131070;
    else if(input < 45874) factor = 163837;
    else if(input < 52428) factor = 218450;
    else if(input < 58981) factor = 327675;

    return factor;
}
```

Comment: *Why* can't you use division or modulo? Integer division is usually really fast.

Comment: `std::lower_bound` might be a good alternative.

Comment: Learn about binary searching?

Comment: do you need to have the factors exactly the numbers you have writen in your example?

Comment: are you missing `return factor;` ?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude We are running on DSP. And divison operation is costly we are running it thousands of times. Sorry I did not mention this details.

Comment: Note that if you write x/6553, the compiler generates a multiplication and some shifts and subtractions, but no division. You could always do the same...

Comment: sound like a job for binary search if you ask me

Comment: Check what assembler code is produced by `input * 2 / 13107` (i.e. input / 6553.5). As Marc Glisse mentions above, it might not use division at all.

Comment: a good compiler always optimizes division by a constant into multiplications. See https://godbolt.org/g/oTy2H3

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude On many CPUs, integer division is actually very slow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could prepare a table containing `72816` repeated `13107` times, `81918` repeated `19660-13107` times, and so on, and just check upper bound (58981). If within bounds, just return `table[input]` else return `0` as you currently (should) do.

No division, no modulo, just some allocated memory (well below 1 megabyte), and pre-computed table.

Proof of concept:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int32_t table[58981];

void prepare_table()
{
    int32_t input,factor;
    for (input=0;input<sizeof(table)/sizeof(table[0]);input++)
    {
    // just reusing your code as-is, but only to create the table

    if(input < 13107) factor = 72816;
    else if(input < 19660) factor = 81918;
    else if(input < 26214) factor = 93621;
    else if(input < 32767) factor = 109225;
    else if(input < 39321) factor = 131070;
    else if(input < 45874) factor = 163837;
    else if(input < 52428) factor = 218450;
    else if(input < 58981) factor = 327675;

    table[input] = factor;
    }

}
int GetScalingFactor(int input)
{
    return input < sizeof(table)/sizeof(table[0]) ? table[input] : 0;
}

int main() {

   prepare_table();

   printf("%d => %d\n",19600,GetScalingFactor(19600));
   printf("%d => %d\n",26200,GetScalingFactor(26200));
   printf("%d => %d\n",58000,GetScalingFactor(58000));
   printf("%d => %d\n",60000,GetScalingFactor(60000));

}
```

so it's memory vs computation tradeoff. If you cannot afford the cache miss, then you have no option left other than division or multiple tests.

Comment: Cache memory is limited on the processor we are running, this may lead to frequent cache misses. Tried this earlier on a different issue, this didnt helped

Comment: You can minimize array size with something like `struct { int lowValue, int threshold; int highValue; } a[1 + (58981 / 1000)];`.

Comment: Ok but then value must be divided and OP wants to avoid division

Answer (score 3):

Using `std::lower_bound` from  in c++:

```
int GetScalingFactor(int input)
{
    const unsigned int inputs[] =  {13107, 19660, 26214, 32767, 39321, 45874, 52428, 58981};
    const int factors[] = {72816, 81918, 93621, 109225, 131070, 163837, 218450, 327675, 0};

    auto it = std::lower_bound(std::begin(inputs), std::end(inputs), input + 1);
    return factors[std::distance(std::begin(inputs), it)];
}
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/IYmRBl)

Comment: But how is it implemented internally?

Comment: @IanAbbott: By a [binary search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm), so `O(log(n))`.

Comment: @LPs: It has a lower complexity, but as usual, to test speed, you have to mesure (and it also depends of input frequency).

Comment: @Jarod42 was disappointed to find that gcc and clang refuse to inline this into a fully unwrapped binary search on implicit values. A constexpr implementation of a template-expanded binary search would no doubt turn the entire code into a few compares. In any case, you probably want to make inputs and factors `static const`.

Comment: Instead of hoping that the compiler will generate just a few compares, why not simply write a few compares. To assume that some exotic DSP has support for a perfectly-implemented C++ compiler is probably quite naive.

Answer (score 1):

Why use data when we can compute a binary search at compile time with template expansion?

Synopsis: This code generates a custom lower_bound implementation for each sequence of indexes.

Preconditions: Each index must appear in the tuple in ascending order.

Results: on clang 3.9.1 no input array is generated. The compiler merely compares each bound in the most efficient order. GCC decides to create an array and effectively implement lower_bound itself (wow!)

code:

```
#include <utility>
#include <tuple>

// turn values into types
template<std::size_t I> using index = std::integral_constant<std::size_t, I>;

// termination case    
template<class T, class Tuple, std::size_t it>
std::size_t iteration(T value, Tuple&&, index<it>, index<0>)
{
    return it;
}

// end of search 'else' path which will not be taken but there must
// be code available at compile time 
template<class T, class Tuple, std::size_t first, std::size_t count, std::enable_if_t<(first >= count)>* = nullptr>
std::size_t iteration(T value, Tuple&& tuple, index<first>, index<count>)
{
    return count-1;
}

// normal iteration of the lower_bound loop    
template<class T, class Tuple, std::size_t first, std::size_t count, std::enable_if_t<(first < count)>* = nullptr>
std::size_t iteration(T value, Tuple&& tuple, index<first>, index<count>)
{
    constexpr auto step = count / 2;
    constexpr auto it = first + step;
    if(std::get<it>(tuple) < value)
    {
        return iteration(value, std::forward<Tuple>(tuple), index<it>(), index<step + 1>());
    }
    else {
        return iteration(value, std::forward<Tuple>(tuple), index<first>(), index<step>());
    }
}

// expand out a lower-bound algorithm from a tuple of bounds
template<class Tuple, class T>
constexpr std::size_t tuple_lower_bound(Tuple&& tuple, const T& value)
{
    constexpr auto count = index<std::tuple_size<std::decay_t<Tuple>>::value>();
    constexpr auto first = index<0>();
    return iteration(value, std::forward<Tuple>(tuple), first, count);
}


int GetScalingFactor(int input)
{
    static constexpr auto indexes = std::make_tuple(13107, 19660, 26214, 32767, 39321, 45874, 52428, 58981);
    static constexpr std::array<int, std::tuple_size<std::decay_t<decltype(indexes)>>::value + 1> factors = 
    {{
        72816, 81918, 93621, 109225, 131070, 163837, 218450, 327675, 0
        }};

    auto i = tuple_lower_bound(indexes, input + 1);
    return factors[i];
}


int main()
{
    extern int get_input();
    auto s1 = GetScalingFactor(get_input());
    return s1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The local variable factor is not very useful.

I think you can't really optimize a sequence of "if else" but you can think
to what are the more common case and test them first. So most of the time only the first condition will be process.

```
    int GetScalingFactor(int input) {

        if(input < 13107) return 72816; // most common case
        else if(input < 19660) return 81918; // second common case
        else if(input < 26214) return 93621; // ...
        else if(input < 32767) return 109225;
        else if(input < 39321) return 131070;
        else if(input < 45874) return 163837;
        else if(input < 52428) return 218450;
        else if(input < 58981) return 327675;
        else return 0;
   }
```

Comment: To sort by frequency, you have to test both bounds, which might complexify a lot the function.

Answer (score 0):

If the compiler implements fast division by a constant (using multiplication and shifts), the following function will work:

```
int GetScalingFactor(int input)
{
    static const int factors[] =
    {
        72816, 72816, 81918, 93621, 109225, 131070, 163837, 218450, 327675
    };

    if (input < 0)
    {
        input = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        input = (input * 2 + 1) / 13107;
        if (input >= sizeof(factors) / sizeof(factors[0]))
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }
    return factors[input];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Given that the input is completely arbitrary and there's no case that's more likely than the others, then you can rewrite the checks as a hard-coded binary search where you split the searched data intervals in two parts with every if statement:

```
if(input < 32767ul)
{
  if(input < 19660ul)
  {
    ...
  }
  ...
}
else if(input < 45874ul)
{
  ...
}
```

And so on (draw it on paper as a binary search tree before coding, if that helps). This reduces the number of comparisons to "O log(n)" and is the best you can achieve short of creating a huge look-up table of 58981 items, where `input` is the index - which would be the best performing solution in terms of execution speed.

Also you code is bugged, you shouldn't be mixing unsigned variables with `int`. Switch data type to `uint_fast32_t`.